Find out mapping of temperature sensors on Lenovo Yoga L13
I am monitoring my systems temperatures through watch -n 2 sensors and get the following output:
Every 2,0s: sensors                                                                                                                                                                                           yoga: Thu Jun 20 09:56:17 2024

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0°C

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          17.20 V

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
fan2:           0 RPM
CPU:           +1.0°C
GPU:           +1.0°C
temp3:         +4.0°C
temp4:        +65.0°C
temp5:            N/A
temp6:            N/A
temp7:        +16.0°C
temp8:        +66.0°C

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +13.20 V)
curr1:         3.00 A  (max =  +3.16 A)

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
(crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +36.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +47.0°C

As you can see the temp4 and temp8 sensors are showing the highest temperatures with 65°C and 66°C respectively. How can I find out which sensors are mapped to these names?
